# Django test.Client is logged in but passed as AnonymousUser in views

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-testing

I have a weird problem here...

I am trying to test a @login_required views so I wrote this code:

```py
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test import Client
from .models import SiteEcommerce
from .models import Client as TestDbClient
from .models import MyCustomEmailUser


class DataBaseTestCase(TestCase):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DataBaseTestCase, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.c = Client()  # instantiate the Django test client
        self.user = MyCustomEmailUser.objects.all()[0]

    def test_method(self):
        """
        Test of the settings page.
        """
        self.c.login(username=self.user.email, password=self.user.password)
        print self.user.is_authenticated()
        response = self.client.get('/main/settings/%s' % self.website.idsite)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

The view called `settings_view` where I am printing the `request.user`

The problem is that in the test `print self.user.is_authenticated()` give `True` BUT the `request.user` in the view return `AnonymousUser`

Comment: I've got the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52982653/anonymoususer-with-django-test-client-login Did you find a solution for this since?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, there is no need to create a new client with `self.c = Client()` - just use `self.client`. You should not access the database in the `__init__` method. Instead, you should set the user in either the `setUp` or [`setupTestData`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.force_login)  method.

```
def setUp(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user = MyCustomEmailUser.objects.all()[0]
```

If you want to check whether the client login worked, you should check the value of `self.client.login(...)`. There is no point checking `self.user.is_authenticated()`, because it will always return `True`.

Your login in not working, because `self.user.password` is the hashed password, not the actual password.

You can use [`force_login`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TestCase.setUpTestData) instead.

```
self.client.force_login(self.user)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Alasdair but I got this error: `Save with update_fields did not affect any rows.`

Comment: I'm not sure what would cause that error. It might be because you have used `__init__` instead of `setUp`. If changing that doesn't fix the problem, then you'll need to provide more info, including the full traceback.

Comment: I've got the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52982653/anonymoususer-with-django-test-client-login `force_login` instead of `login` gives the same result (with no errors whatsoever)

Answer (score 0):

Short version: "It's your fixtures, maybe."

---

Long version...

I ran into this after upgrading to 1.11. Took me a minute to figure out, but when you upgrade versions, Django upgrades how many iterations the backend password hasher uses to test passwords.

The result of this is that in your tests you may have a fixture with a line like:

```
"password": "sha1$6efc0$f93efe9fd7542f25a7be94871ea45aa95de57161",
```

And in your test you might have something like:

```
self.client.login(username='pandora', password='password')
```

Turns out that when you bumped your Django version and got those extra hashes, that old fixture no longer works because the new Django hashes the password provided by the test code more times than the value that you had in your fixture.

The solution:

1. On your dev machine, create a user with the password you want in your fixture.
2. Find the admin page for that user.
3. Copy that user into your fixture where it was failing.

Alternatively, here's a hashed value you can use in your fixtures that works for the password "password":

```
"password": "pbkdf2_sha256$36000$OIQCpvIXZil8$y7qUtb3Y0imzu1ATn4vQZeVtu7MuPg0zUqX5oBUL2zM=",
```

Fun stuff. Sorry, not fun. Dumb.