# AnonymousUser with django.test.client.login()

Tags: django, selenium, testing, authentication

I'm testing login function.

```
def setUpClass(cls):
    super(BasePage_loggedin, cls).setUpClass()
    cls.selenium = WebDriver()
    cls.client = Client()
    cls.user_1 = MyUser.objects.create_user(username='myself',password='12345')
    cls.client.login(username=cls.user_1.username, password=cls.user_1.password)

    # create session cookie:
    session = SessionStore()
    session[SESSION_KEY] = cls.user_1.pk
    session[BACKEND_SESSION_KEY] = settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS[0]
    session[HASH_SESSION_KEY] = cls.user_1.get_session_auth_hash()
    session.save()

    # Finally, create the cookie dictionary
    cookie = {
        'name': settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME,
        'value': session.session_key,
        'secure': False,
        'path': '/',
    }
    # add the session cookie
    cls.selenium.get('{}'.format(cls.live_server_url))
    cls.selenium.add_cookie(cookie)
    cls.selenium.refresh()
    cls.selenium.get('{}'.format(cls.live_server_url))
```

So I can pass the login page, but then, when I do `request.user` to check the data for this user, it's an [AnonymousUser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/auth/#anonymoususer-object)

Answer (score 0):

When you're creating the user that way - I believe it has to do with the password. Setting the password to a string like that doesn't do what you *think* it would do.

You could create the user like that - then add this after the user creation but before the login:

```
cls.user_1.set_password('12345')
cls.user_1.save()
```

Then login the user with something like this:

```
cls.client.login(username=cls.user_1.username, password='12345')
```

I believe it has something to do with the hashing of the password or something along those lines - it's been a while since I stumbled around with it, but I remember having the exact same issue as you.

Something like this should work:

```
cls.selenium = WebDriver()
cls.client = Client()
cls.user_1 = MyUser.objects.create_user(username='myself',password='12345')
cls.user_1.set_password('12345')
cls.user_1.save()
cls.client.login(username=cls.user_1.username, password='12345')
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your settings.py and try below codes.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
        'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
            'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication', # needed only up to the test env
            'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        )
    }
```